# What noises can be sliced?

Tags: animation, noise

A well-known property of Perlin noise (with FBM) is that if you take a slice of it, the result is still Perlin noise.  So, by taking successive slices of 4D  noise, you get smoothly shifting 3D noise, like a cloud or a lava lamp.

What other noises have this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Worley noise](http://www.rhythmiccanvas.com/research/papers/worley.pdf), also known as [cellular noise](https://thebookofshaders.com/12/), has the same property. It just as easily implemented as Perlin noise and easily extends to higher dimensions. Thus the slicing of 4D Worley noise will produce a 3D Worley noise. However, it is not necessarily a noise function but rather a texture function, producing cellular-like characteristics. With FBM applied to Worley noise some interesting patterns can be created.

You can find additional types of procedural noise functions in [this](http://graphics.cs.kuleuven.be/publications/LLCDDELPZ10STARPNF/) survey paper.